# Generating random numbers directly inside a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I'm adding a *Random Number* to the end of my *Ajax* URLs via Javascript or PHP. I'm wondering if I could do the same just inside of my `.htaccess` file, when I'm rewriting them using mod_rewrite.

Is there any way to making a *Random Number* or *String* in a `.htaccess` file on-the-fly?

**Edit:** I don't have any problem in my current code. I just want to know if I could generate a random number in the .htaccess file or not. I've already searched the 'net, but couldn't find anything helpful yet.

**Update:** Well, I just realized that `Ajax` requests caches on the *Client-side*, but the `.htaccess` works on the *Server-side*. So, my question seems totally useless now (at least in my own case), but thanks for sharing your ideas.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It smells severely like you're having XY problems, trying to implement a broken solution to a completely unrelated problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Niels Thanks for the comment, but as I said, I just want to know if there is any way to make a random number or string inside of a `.htaccess` file or not. I don't have any problem at all, my current code works fine. :)

Comment: My point is - the only reason you'd want to do this is to have an implicit cachebust in the URL. Which won't work if you do it on the serverside, *after* the caching options are evaluated. As such, there's no reasonable use case I can think of to want this behaviour, hence why I think you're stumped on implementing something that won't fix your original problem. Also, if there were a valid use case for it, a mature product like Apache would support it out of the box.

Comment: @Niels now I understand why nobody asked it before and I couldn't found anything on the 'net! Please take a look at OP update! Thanks again for sharing your thoughts! :)

Comment: you're welcome, and next time remember the XY-problem - don't ask for help with the intended solution, ask for help with the *problem*, and people will appreciate it if you also share what you *think* the solution could be.

Answer (score 4):

I know, this is an old question as well as the fact, that the problem is somewhere else. Though, this could be something you can maybe use for other things.
The RewriteEngine knows variables, so you could use conditions or just add the `%{TIME}` to the call

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} <30
RewriteRule .* /first.html [L]
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} >29
RewriteRule .* /second.html [L]
```

You could also play around with the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [RewriteMap with the `prg` MapType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg). This would enable you to call an external program to process the RewriteRule. And that script could do whatever you want…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean I use another application or script to generate the random number and then send it back somehow to the `Apache` to continuing the process? Consider that I don't want any external application process the RewriteRule!