# .htaccess - add unique hash at end of url

Tags: .htaccess

i like to add unique hash at end of my url

example if url is   www.site.com/page.html    i like each time user visit to make

```
www.site.com/page.html?asdao238rsv
www.site.com/page.html?2498yu234bj
www.site.com/page.html?sdn3i9sfkl9
```

i find a .htaccess that add  a static text after url  but i like unique text

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ThisWillBeAddedAfterUrl g(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?ThisWillBeAddedAfterUrl [L,QSA,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317945/generating-random-numbers-directly-inside-a-htaccess-file

Comment: cant find that what im loking

Comment: OK: first the basics: a `.htaccess` style file _cannot_ add anything to a url you send to a client. It only works on requests to urls that are send from the client to the server. What is the point in adding some random string to the _incoming_ url on the server side when all you do is process it afterwards yourself? That is _not_ what you want to do, I'd say.

Comment: Do you have access to the server or vhost config?

Comment: This needs to be done in PHP code

Comment: what i need to add in code

Answer (score 0):

You can add `%{TIME}` instead of static string like following :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1.php?%{TIME} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I believe it is, it's timestamp

Comment: 2 requests can be handled close enough to get the same timestamp, `%{TIME}` is only precise down to the second.

Comment: my page now load slowwww and im getting this url
site.com/page?20150213192732&20150213192732&20150213192732&20150213192732&20150213192732&20150213192732&20150213192732......  and this repeat a lot of times

Comment: @arlind, this can't be done with `htaccess`, if you check the website response, there is a redirection from `/` to `?generate-id`

Comment: so how this can be done . do i need to add any code to my files

Comment: yes, in your `index.php` file for example you can add a code snippet that will check if `?generated-id` exists in the url if not redirect to `index.php?generated-id`